# Show Views Count Next to the Questions on StackOverflow's Mobile UI

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, mobile-web

I would to propose a small UI tweak to the current version of StackOverflow's Mobile-friendly optimized site for displaying the ***number of views*** next to the question.

To illustrate this better, here is a mock-up version that I have created using Pixlr app. Please ignore the *font* and *icon* style as I am not good at graphics but you can use them as a guideline.

[image]

As you can see, there is a enough room to accommodate and display (*without cluttering*) the number of views along with a small graphical(of course,  using CSS/SVG) eye icon. After posting a question, the next big thing to know is how many times it has been seen by the fellow SO community members. Views count are very important as they tell you if your question is getting any attention or not. It would be also good to display these views count somewhere within(i.e. once you open) the question too. Say, for example, at the bottom area right next to *Asked n days ago* section. Not sure about this one, I would leave it to SE's UI expert team. But, for the moment, to begin with, I would be glad if SE's UI team could add this small tweak to the current mobile version to display the *views count* as proposed(or even better way they can think of) in the above mock-up/screenshot.

For the time being, I use the  workaround by clicking on the "full site" link located in the footer section which gives a full-site web browser based page. But, this (switching back n forth) totally defeats the whole purpose of having mobile-friendly SO website.

Comment: Yeah and also when you browse some question.

Comment: This is a really great idea! And show the views not only for your own questions but for any question